# Probability involving independent experiments

Tags: probability

I am having an issue grasping the concepts on how to apply independent experiments to this problem. I know that our set that we look at is $50 \leq x \leq 60$ but not sure how to approach this other than that. Since they are independent we can split up the and statements $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$ is it like $P(e^{−0.003})P(e^{−0.005x})$ but how would I plug in the hours?

Transistors are purchased from two independent sources $A$ and $B$. The probability that one purchased from $A$ will not fail prior to $x$ hours of operation is $e^{−0.003}$, and the probability that one purchased from B will not fail prior to $x$ hours is a $e^{−0.005}$. Given that a transistor was observed to fail after between $50$ to $60$ hours of operations, what is the probability that it was purchased from $A$?

Comment: Have you integrated over the time interval?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  The CDF is given, so no integration is required.  This is a Bayes' Rule problem.

Comment: PS: The event that the resistor fails and is from A, is *not independent* from the event that the resistor fails and is from B. Rather they are mutually exclusive (aka disjoint) events. [They cannot both happen.]

Answer (score 1):

You want $\mathsf P(A \mid F)$, where $F$ is the event that the resistor failed in the interval, $A,B$ the events that the resistor is from the relevant source. [Note: that the sources are independent does not mean that the events of a resistor coming from a sources are.]

We have been given the CDF for each source and interval $50<x\leqslant 60$, so *assuming* there was equal (prior)probability of being from each source, this  tells us, since $\mathsf P(X\leqslant x;\lambda)$ $=$ $1-e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1)}$, that:

$$\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(B)=\tfrac 12\\\mathsf P(F\mid A) = -(e^{-0.003\times 60}-e^{-0.003\times 50})\\\mathsf P(F\mid B) = -(e^{-0.005\times 60}-e^{-0.005\times 50})\\\mathsf P(F)=\mathsf P(F\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(F\mid B)\mathsf P(B)$$

The rest is just an application of Bayes' Rule.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So the one issue that I am having is when I try to calculate P(F | A) with those hours I end up getting a negative value? and one of the things we were taught was that all probability has to be between 0 and 1.

P(F∣A)=(e^−0.003×60^−e−0.003×50) = -.0254